# What are these key-value store semantics called?

Tags: publish-subscribe, key-value

Imagine a simple key-value server that allows the following verbs:

PUT key value - Sets the value of key to value
GET key - Gets the value of the key if it set, or indicates it is missing
WAIT key timeout - If the value of the key is set, get it immediately. Otherwise, block/wait until somebody else PUTs the key, returning as quickly as possible. If the timeout is reached, indicate failure.

These semantics are somewhat similar to Futures and Promises in various local execution environments, but in a distributed environment, I'm imagining it is typically accomplished with some combination of a messaging protocol and a key-value store.

I am wondering if anybody is either:

1. Aware of a good name for these semantics so I can start googling
2. Aware of a tool that offers this out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the semantics are called -- but this is accomplishable using redis blocking.

Using blocking pop/pushes with one-element lists, we can implement the GETs as follows:

> BRPOPLPUSH q q 0

If the list already exists, it will return the value immediately, and then just add it back to the list. If it doesn't it'll block until a value is added (or you can set a timeout using the last arg).

To set a value, you can just push to the list.

> LPUSH q 1

If you want to ensure true SET semantics, you might prefer a transaction

```
MULTI
DEL q
LPUSH q 1
EXEC
```